# There is a little space in my div and h1 heading

Tags: html, css

I want to make the whole container look like only one. But there is little space in border of container and background of h3 heading. This problem is some time occur in one or two containers when I change pixels of border. Pls help....

Image of result:

> [image: image of result]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Block and Inline element</title>
    <style>
        * {
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .container {
            width: 650px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 2px solid rgb(184, 183, 183);
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        #inline,#inline-block,#block{
            display: block;
            padding: 8px 5px;

        }

        details {
            background-color: rgb(194, 152, 152);
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom:3px ;
            padding: 1px;

        }

        h3 {
            background-color: rgb(207, 203, 203);
           border-top-right-radius: 3px;
           border-top-left-radius:3px ;
           border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
        }

        /* main display propereties */
        .inline {
            display: inline;
            width: 80px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .inline-block {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 80px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .block {
            display: block;
            width: 80px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 20px;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Display:Inline</h3>
        <span id="inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, praesentium! Ipsam nemo
            voluptas sequi et. Quas sequi <span class="inline">cupiditate</span> <span class="inline">cupiditate</span>
            fuga ab qui aliquam, aliquid, perferendis provident laborum vel soluta neque.</span>
        <details>With and Height are not effective,only padding effects in Inline display.</details>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h3>Display:Inline-Block</h3>
        <span id="inline-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, praesentium! Ipsam
            nemo voluptas sequi et. Quas sequi <span class="inline-block">cupiditate</span> <span
                class="inline-block">cupiditate</span> fuga ab qui aliquam, aliquid, perferendis provident laborum vel
            soluta neque.</span>
        <details>With,Height and Padding are effective in Inline-Block display and elements are displayed side by side.
        </details>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h3>Display:Block</h3>
        <span id="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, praesentium! Ipsam nemo
            voluptas sequi et. Quas sequi <span class="block">cupiditate</span> <span class="block">cupiditate</span>
            fuga ab qui aliquam, aliquid, perferendis provident laborum vel soluta neque.</span>
        <details>With,Height and Padding are effective in Inline-Block display but elements are not displayed side by
            side.</details>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting .container overflow: hidden and leave h3 without any border-radius. Does it do the trick?

Comment: no bro it did not help.